# C# .NET Generate once a string array which his indexes are string values from a table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a table contains the columns Title and Info.

I would like to create an array it's index will be the Title, and actual value of the array in that index is the Info in the same row.

So if I have 3 Rows like that:

```
Title      Info

ABC        Hi

DEF        Sup

GHI        Hello
```

I would like to ask for `StringArray["ABC"]`, and this will return "Hi".

How can I do that?

Thanks Guy

Comment: @ScottM. - He's probably unaware of the existence of a dictionary class. Instead of being combative it would probably be more beneficial to just say "Take a look at the Dictionary class."

Comment: Are your indexes guaranteed to be unique? If they aren't then a dictionary wont work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a `Dictionary<String, String>`, not a string array.

```
var myStrings = new Dictionary<String, String>();
myStrings.Add("ABC", "Hi");
myStrings.Add("DEF", "Sup");
myStrings.Add("GHI", "Hello");

Console.WriteLine(myStrings["ABC"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can only be indexed with an integer.  You would have to use `Dictionary<string, string>`, or some other type that implements `IDictionary<string, string>`, or you could implement your own type with a string indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Dictionary for that

You can do in this way

```
Dictionary<string, string> Book = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Book.Add("ABC","Hi");
Book.Add("DEF","Sup");
Book.Add("GHI","Hello");
```

so on and so forth.

So then when you say

`Book["ABC"]` it will return `Hi`

Answer (score 1):

You should use dictionary to implement it.

```
var table = new Dictionary<string,string>(
{"ABC", "Hi"},
{"DEF", "Sup"},
{"GHI", "Hello"}
);
```

now you can use it

```
var info = table["ABC"];
```

you should be careful an exception will be thrown if you use unexisted key

you can use TryGetValue to avoid this exception

```
string info;

if(!table.TryGetValue("ABC", out info))
{
  info = "default value if required";
}
```